# Math.sin gives "unexpected execution" error in Standard ML of New Jersey

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I'm using Standard ML of New Jersey. When I run `Math.sin 3`, I get:

> unexpected exception (bug?) in SML/NJ: Io [Io: openIn failed on "C:\cygwin\home\ jhr\Work\smlnj\release\sml.boot.x86-win32\smlnj\basis.cm\x86-win32\basis.cm", win32-bin-prim-io:checkHndl: openRd: failed] raised at:
>
> Basis/Implementation/IO/bin-io-fn.sml:617.25-617.71 ../cm/util/safeio.sml:30.11 ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:42.54`

Comment: It looks like your installation is broken, or there's a conflict between Windows and cygwin.

Comment: Note that you should write `Math.sin 3.0` if you want it to typechek.